# Sagas and fetch promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I've been banging my head on the desk  for the last few minutes here due to this API request...

I have the following code:

Saga:

```
export function * registerFlow () {
  while (true) {
    const request = yield take(authTypes.SIGNUP_REQUEST)
    console.log('authSaga request', request)
    let response = yield call(authApi.register, request.payload)
    console.log('authSaga response', response)
    if (response.error) {
      return yield put({ type: authTypes.SIGNUP_FAILURE, response })
    }

    yield put({ type: authTypes.SIGNUP_SUCCESS, response })
  }
}
```

API request:

```
// Inject fetch polyfill if fetch is unsuported
if (!window.fetch) { const fetch = require('whatwg-fetch') }

const authApi = {
  register (userData) {
    fetch(`http://localhost/api/auth/local/register`, {
      method  : 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Accept'        : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body    : JSON.stringify({
        name      : userData.name,
        email     : userData.email,
        password  : userData.password
      })
    })
    .then(statusHelper)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => error)
    .then(data => data)
  }
}

function statusHelper (response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
  }
}

export default authApi
```

The API request does return a valid object however the return from the Saga call always is undefined. Can anyone guide me to where I am wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,

Bruno

Comment: What good are `.catch(error => error).then(data => data)`? You really should omit them (especially the `catch` that transforms every rejection into a fulfillment)

Comment: Where exactly do you get `undefined`?

Comment: I am getting undefined inside the Saga, more specifically, the console.log('authSaga', response)

Comment: Even if I omit it the problem persists.

Comment: I was looking for a sample of web-api used with saga. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the promises from your function. Make it

```
const authApi = {
  register (userData) {
    return fetch(`http://localhost/api/auth/local/register`, {
//  ^^^^^^
      method  : 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Accept'        : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/json'
      },
      body    : JSON.stringify({
        name      : userData.name,
        email     : userData.email,
        password  : userData.password
      })
    })
    .then(statusHelper)
    .then(response => response.json());
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem!

Thank you so much!